# Chromedriver logging disable

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone suggest the method to disable chromedriver logs getting generated on standard output in java, so that,

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550
>   (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 42936, only local
>   connections are allowed

will not appear on standard output.

I have already tried the below mentioned combinations, but none of them has worked:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--log-level=3");
options.addArguments("--disable-logging");
options.addArguments("--silent");
            caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            ChromeDriverService service =new ChromeDriverService.Builder().withWhitelistedIps("").withVerbose(false).build(); 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true"); 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "chromedriver.log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
```